# Mobile Safari Cellular Only Loading Error

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari

I'm hoping someone here can help. We are experiencing a problem with an HTML/CSS only website we've developed but only in mobile Safari over a cellular network. The website loads on devices if they are connected to a wifi network though, and in other browsers like Opera Mini over the cellular network. Have a look at this video:
http://youtu.be/W0lF6OwgLhI

In case you can't see from the video, the site URL is http://www.ringelgroup.com
This same issue has been seen on multiple devices in various locations.
Any ideas on what's going on?

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution from another post
[Remove wierd characters in xml output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242784/remove-wierd-characters-in-xml-output)

You have to set the header for your content.  In your example it would be text/html I think because it's html.

```
<head>
  <title>Page name</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```